# How to show data values on a graph as "x" in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, graph

I am using Swing library to plot a simple line graph. To show the data values in the graph I use Graphics.fillOval to create a dot, which represents the data. But how do I show the data values as a small "x" instead of a dot?

Comment: Something like `drawLine(x-3,y-3,x+3,y+3); drawLine(x-3,y+3,x+3,y-3);`?

Answer (score 1):

For example, you can draw a figure like "x" by drawing two lines.

Example:

```
void drawX(Graphics g, int x, int y, int size) {
    g.drawLine(x - size, y - size, x + size, y + size);
    g.drawLine(x + size, y - size, x - size, y + size);
}
```

Comment: @MikeCAT As promised.  Sorry I was slow to get there.